# Basics of simple text data collection iOS apps. Where is the data stored?

Tags: ios, database

I'm trying to inch my way towards building a data collection app for a specific application. Eventually I want to have drop-down and manual text entries, building a dataset that I can export as a CSV and manipulate further in Excel.

I've used some apps like [Fulcrum](http://fulcrumapp.com/), but eventually I'd like to add some more functionality to the app. Basically I'm trying to figure out how these apps are storing the entered data, then pushing it to a server when internet access is available. What are some general options that I should explore to do this magic?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740392/how-to-store-user-data-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store data with Core Data, you can use the native API's and methods or external libraries which will make a lot easier all the work, such as [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and more.

If you want native I recommend you [AppCoda tutorials](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/), you need to do a lot of research to start with core data.

And also you can use an external library to store this info into a server or in the cloud.

I've heard [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) is great.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! It's amazing how a keyword can get you unstuck. Never heard of Core Data until now. The research continues! Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to take a deeper dive into Core Data, Tim Roadley has written a pretty comprehensive book on the topic. The current edition of the book is in Objective-C, though I believe a Swift version is on the way.