# How and When to Store Settings & User Data in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I developed an iPhone game in Swift using Xcode. It needs to store settings as well as user data. How do I get the app's settings and data to save when it is restarted or quit?

Comment: Save your settings in NSUserDefaults when the app closes and read them back when the app reopens. There's already plenty of examples on SO that you can follow.

Comment: @EricD. D I know the NSUserDefaults before I asked here. but I heard it is not safe to a large file. I think I will be blocked from this question. thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're right that NSUserDefaults is not suited for large files, but you should have told us in your question that you wanted to save large files and that you already knew about NSUserDefaults... How are we supposed to guess otherwise? :)

Comment: @EricD. Yes, I missed that point. that is my mistake. ;-0

Comment: Why are "settings" a large file? Don't conflate "settings" and "user data".

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi  My  application contained a lot of image files and user can edit that image files. I think that point is not Good at to setting NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I think there is now enough information to undo downvotes and retract votes to close.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi thanks very much:->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, use `NSUserDefaults` for settings. For "large files" it's more likely you mean "user data". In that case, you can use [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1) or store your own [`NSCoding`-compliant data model](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) via `NSKeyedArchiver` (and unarchived via `NSKeyedUnarchiver`) or their `...Secure...` alternatives to write to your app's documents.

Rather than save only [when the application's state changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW5), you should probably persist small changes as they're made (this is basically what `NSUserDefaults` does) or as some logical group of changes are made (what constitutes a "logical group" depends entirely on the nature of the data and your app and is therefore up to you).

So: Identify the "settings" and store them the right way (in `NSUserDefaults`). Then identify your user's game data and store *that* the right way (in some sort of data file).

Comment: For user data, see also, Caleb's answer to this SO Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740392/how-to-store-user-data-ios

Comment: @Josha Nozzi It is very useful. thanks to detail comment.

Comment: Sure thing. :-) Adding: If you use Core Data, search the guide I linked for "external file". You could have an entity "Image" with metadata (like "title" and "width" / "height") stored in its properties but its actual binary file content stored as an external file. This will keep your Core Data store responsive and your memory footprint low when fetching/listing all images available to the user (ie, it avoids loading *everything*, contents and all, when all you want is metadata for a list).

Comment: If you go the non-Core-Data route (ie, your own distinct document formats), you'll probably want one file for your "manifest" (your list of images and their metadata) and a subfolder full of the actual images, which accomplishes the same thing as the Core Data comment I just posted above.