# Changing values in plist - Doesn't change value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am using this simple method I found to write to a plist but it doesn't seem to work:

```
-(IBAction)modifyPlist:(id)sender{

NSBundle *mainBundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path=[mainBundle pathForResource:@"Preferences" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
[[dict objectForKey:@"Root"] setBool:YES forKey:@"startup"];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the file into memory, and modifying that memory, but you're not writing it back to disk. You'll want to use `NSDictionary`'s `-writeToFile:atomically:`

```
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

[Reference link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know exactly what you're doing and this is (for whatever reason) your design decision -
because you're about to **write to your app's bundle**.

That'll certainly fail under Sandboxing and is generally a bad, bad idea.

If you've after storing user defaults please read up on the Mac way of storing preferences:
[**Preferences and Settings Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make a path to the plist in the Documents directory (not the bundle directory)
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences.plist"];

// Then after creating or making changes to your dictionary, write your dictionary out to the plist file
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Maybe look at:
[Should I use NSUserDefaults or a plist to store data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058858/should-i-use-nsuserdefaults-or-a-plist-to-store-data/27332822#27332822)